# How to access an OnPremise system from AWS using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sap-erp, hybrid-cloud, sap-cloud-connector

I have an OnPremise (SAP) system which exposes data via RESTful services and remote functions (RFC). How can I access these data from a Node.JS application running on AWS? Which AWS service will be useful in this scenario to connect to the OnPremise VPN to facilitate the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) to extend your on premise infrastructure with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for VPN connections: either a site-to-site VPN, which uses a [customer gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/your-cgw.html) and a [virtual private gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/faqs/#Virtual_private_gateway).  Alternatively, [AWS Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) is an actual physical connection between your on premise data center and an AWS data center.

DirectConnect offers much better performance, but requires third parties to install a physical cable, and so can take several days to implement. If you're looking for a solution that's independent of hardware, then a site-to-site VPN could be a good fit.